# insert and fetch binary image from database in asp using entity farmework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to capture image from webcam and also from Android mobile camera and insert binary code of image into database. i am using Javascript function to capture the image, now image is captured and having it into a variable now i need to store it into SQL Database and display it from database.

DB is:

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test] (
                [Id]   INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
                [data] VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
            );


    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <!doctype html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>WebcamJS Test Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; }
            h2, h3 { margin-top:0; }
            form { margin-top: 15px; }
            form > input { margin-right: 15px; }
            #results { float:right; margin:20px; padding:20px; border:1px solid; background:#ccc; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="results">Your captured image will appear here...</div>

        <h1>WebcamJS Test Page</h1>
        <h3>Demonstrates simple 320x240 capture &amp; display</h3>

        <div id="my_camera"></div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <!-- First, include the Webcam.js JavaScript Library -->
        <%--<script type="text/javascript" src="../webcam.min.js"></script>--%>
        <script src="webcam.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
        <script language="JavaScript">
            Webcam.set({
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                image_format: 'jpeg',
                jpeg_quality: 90
            });
            Webcam.attach('#my_camera');
        </script>

        <!-- A button for taking snaps -->
        <form>
            <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
        </form>

        <!-- Code to handle taking the snapshot and displaying it locally -->
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function take_snapshot() {
                // take snapshot and get image data
                Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
                    // display results in page
                    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
                        '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' +
                        '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
                    document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value = data_uri;
                    //document.getElementById["TextBox1"].innerHTML = data_uri;
                });
            }
        </script>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in C# (since it is not requested if needed in C# or javascript)

**Inserting it**

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ([data]) VALUES(@imageData)", connection )) 
{
    connection.Open();
    var parameter = new SqlParameter("@imageData", SqlDbType.Binary) 
    {
        // here goes your binary data 
        Value = yourCSharpObjectImageData.GetTemplateBuffer().ToArray()
    };
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // do something else ...
}
```

**Retrieving it**

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING ..."))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [data] THUMB FROM test WHERE ID = @ID", connection)) 
{
    connection.Open();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", yourIdHere);
    return command.ExecuteScalar() as byte[];
}
```